# Making `using` declaration inside template before class declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using

Say I have the following code:

```
template<typename X, typename Y, typename Z>
class Foo : public Parent<SomeComplicatedExpressionInvolving<X,Y,Z>> {
  using Useful = SomeComplicatedExpressionInvolving<X,Y,Z>;

  Useful member;
  Useful another_member;
  Useful f(Useful x) { return x; } // etc.
};
```

The `Useful` declaration is useful here because it allows us to write `Useful` in place of some really long expression.

Is it possible to neaten this further and put the `using` declaration *before* the class declaration? Obviously, the following code doesn't compile:

```
template<typename X, typename Y, typename Z>
using Useful = SomeComplicatedExpressionInvolving<X,Y,Z>
class Foo : public Parent<Useful> {      
  Useful member;
  Useful another_member;
  Useful f(Useful x) { return x; } // etc.
};
```

but is there a way to write something to this effect? It may be useful to make multiple `using` declarations in this way (i.e. within the template scope but before a class declaration).

Comment: No.  It either needs to be global with its own template or in the class.

Comment: In many cases similar to this, not having X Y Z and just taking Useful as template argument, then accessing it's classes via e.g. ::mapped_type, was a better solution for me. However this does not always work, and kind of depends on your actual situation not the minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea (+1 for the AndyG's solution) but... just for fun... you can use a template type with default value instead of `using`.

By example

```
template <typename, typename, typename>
struct SomeComplicatedExpressionInvolving
 { };

template <typename>
struct Parent
 { };

template <typename X, typename Y, typename Z,
          typename Useful = Parent<SomeComplicatedExpressionInvolving<X,Y,Z>>>
class Foo : public Useful
 {
   Useful member;
   Useful another_member;
   Useful f(Useful x) { return x; } // etc.
 };

int main ()
 {
   Foo<int, long, int> f;
 }
```

Comment: This is totally the way to do what OP wants, even though there is no `using`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a `using` defined after the template and before the class. However, You could clean up what you do have a little bit with two `using` type aliases

```
template<typename X, typename Y, typename Z>
using Useful_t = SomeComplicatedExpressionInvolving<X,Y,Z>;

template<class X, class Y, class Z>
class Foo : public Parent<Useful_t<X, Y, Z>> {
  using Useful = Useful_t<X, Y, Z>;
  Useful member;
  Useful another_member;
  Useful f(Useful x) { return x; } // etc.
};
```

[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/XNV22706)